# Get Uploader UI elements in onValidate (jQuery S3 Plugin)

Tags: fine-uploader

During the "validate" event, I'm attempting to gain access to the different UI elements within uploader.

As of right now, I only see private methods attached to the `this` context. Almost all of them are "private".

In the qq.Templating object within fine-uploader I see: `getDropProcessing`, etc which are the exact methods I need.

Are these exposed anywhere in the event handler, or on the object where I can access them without knowing the *exact* classes name? Or is there a way to access the `selectorClasses` object?

Example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
onValidate: function(imgData, btnContainer){
    // "this" context is the qq.s3.fineUploader object created.
    var uploader = $(this._options.element), // uploader element
        processingEl = uploader.fineUploader('getDropProcessing'); // does not exist.
}
```

Comment: All of these items are represented in the template you provided.  Why is using a class, attribute, id, etc as a selector that you assigned in your template an issue?

Comment: The idea is that I want this handler to be generic. Meaning, if I have say two uploader instantiated on two different parts of the page, I don't want to have to rewrite this config/function for *each* one.

Comment: What exact (specific) problem are you trying to solve?  Why are you trying to reference the drop processing element in a validate callback?

Answer (score 0):

To gain access to a file item and its children in Fine Uploader UI, use the [`getItemByFileId` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getItemByFileId).  All other elements are represented in your template, so you should be able to select them using whatever class/attribute/ID you have assigned them in your template.

Comment: I looked at that, but the validate event is only passing the following:

    {
        name: "l.jpg",
        size: 277557
    }

Comment: ...then move the logic to another event handler.  There is no DOM representation of the file until the submitted event is triggered.